# multiple level load() doesn't receive the updated data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a three select boxes in a page, where the content of the second select box depends on the content of the first box and the content of the third depends on the content of the second.

Of course, any change in any "parent" box should change the content of all "child" boxes.

Right now, I have this code:

```
$('#lvl1').change(function(){
    // This works
    $('#lvl2').load('/interventions/categories/2?term='+encodeURIComponent($('#lvl1').val()),
                    function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (textStatus == "complete") {
            // This doesn't work ($('#lvl2').val() doesn't reflect the change)
            $('#lvl3').load('/interventions/categories/3?term='+encodeURIComponent($('#lvl2').val()));
        };
    });
});

// This works
$('#lvl2').change(function(){
    $('#lvl3').load('/interventions/categories/3?term='+encodeURIComponent($('#lvl2').val()));
});
```

My thought was to have the lvl3 load inside the callback function on success of the lvl2 load after I changed the lvl1 value, but for some reason, it doesn't wait and still receives the outdated value of lvl2 (and then proceeds to load the wrong content for lvl3).
What am I missing?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Calling both `load()` and `val()` on the same element (`#lvl2`) doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not the same element. $('#lvl2').load(....+$('#lvl1').val()). lvl2 calls the value of lvl1.

Comment: Unless my eyes is fooling me, the code you pasted definitely contains both `$('#lvl2').load()` and `$('#lvl2').val()`.

Comment: Yes that's the point of my question. I want that in the callback function, on success, after lvl2 has finished loading, it passes that value to the lvl3 load.

Comment: Shouldn't this `if (textStatus == "complete") {` be `if (textStatus == "success") {`?

Comment: As a matter of fact... Yes it should.. :-)